# Setting an ASP session variable to Javascript global variable value

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

How can i set the value of a ASP session variable - `Session("CaptchaVal")` . 
I want to assign its value to a Javascript global variable  - `var genValue`.

Answer (score 1):

In your ASP page create a script block with the variable defined:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var genValue = '<%=Session("CaptchaVal")%>';
</script>
```

Of course, that is a simple example.

You need to be careful if you value might contain a single quote.

You should escape the value from the session.

You need to be careful to put that script block prior to any other js code that might attempt to use genValue.

Comment: wont the reverse work ? that what i wanted. but it does not seem to work. i want to assign the session variable to genValue along with some other piece of code.

Comment: @ReshmaCB you are wrong. This code does exactly this: it assign the session variable into JavaScript global variable. Rethink your logic and if you can explain, please do it.

Comment: @ReshmaCB, do you want the Session value to contain whatever is in the javascript value?  My example sets a javascript variable to whatever is in the session.

Comment: @slolife : Thanks i wanted the Session value to contain whatever is in the javascript value. Now instead I opted to use javascript without sending it to the next form. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Since Session variables are stored on the server and javascript is purely on the clientside, simply setting a session variable this way will not work. You need to use a request (either get or post) which will be sent to the server and put your setting of the session variable into that request.
Try looking for ajax request with jquery. That way you can send the needed parameters to an asp file where you can retrieve them and set the session, as the asp files are executed on the server.